# How know if the Angular compiled /dist match with the source code in /src?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-compiler, angular-compiler-cli

I have a compiled 'dist' folder and I want to know if it matches with the source code or is a different version. How can I do it?

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacky solution would be to copy the dist folder into a git project, commit that folder, recompile copy that into the git folder and do a diff. If there is no diff it was from the source.